# Count Cycles not matching on STM32F103C8? Prefetch buffer not working as I think?

Tags: stm32

I have been fighting this subject for a while. I am using STM32F103C8 with the ST-Link V2 on Atollic.

I made some delay functions on assembly. I have been testing this piece of code using a oscilloscope on ATSAM (84 MHz and work perfectly) and on STM32 I also use a CPU register to see the exact amount of cycles on the debugging - DWT (Data Watchpoint and Trace).

When I configure the STM32 CPU clock to 24MHz the exact amount of cycles that I have designed for the time delay is correct. It is, 1 cycle for a decrement assembly instruction and 2 cycles for a branch instruction (on most cases). So, the main loop spend 3 cycles.

When I change the CPU clock to 72MHz each assembly instruction spend twice that time!

Well, the prefecth buffer is 2x64 bits, and the wait states should not let influence the execution CPU time (not thinking on prediction or other code stalls) on this microcontroller? Should it?

Well, on 24MHz the flash memory has no wait state, with higher clock, the CPU should not wait to execute any code. Should it?

I flashing with the release hex to see some difference and did not find any.

My only explanation would be of the ST-LINK V2? Am I right?

Thanks a lot for your time and attention.

This is the piece of the code that matters:

```
asm (".equ fcpu, 72000000\n\t");    //72 MHz
asm (".equ const_ms, fcpu/3000  \n\t"); 
asm (".equ const_us, fcpu/3000000   \n\t"); 

void delay_us(uint32_t valor)   
{
  asm volatile ( "movw r1, #:lower16:const_us   \n\t"
  "movt r1, #:upper16:const_us  \n\t"   
  "mul r0, r0, r1   \n\t"   
  "r_us:    subs r0, r0, #1 \n\t" 
  "bne r_us \n\t");
}

void delay_ms(uint32_t valor)   
{
  asm volatile ("movw r1, #:lower16:const_ms    \n\t"
  "movt r1, #:upper16:const_ms  \n\t"   
  "mul r0, r0, r1   \n\t"   
  "r_ms:    subs r0, r0, #1 \n\t"
  "bne r_ms \n\t");
}
```

Comment: To post code, in a text editor shift it right four spaces, then copy and paste.  Best to avoid tabs.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the wait states of the FLASH memory run at 72MHz. It is good to read the documentation :).

Place the code in the SRAM and you will get what you want.

For the good results fro the FLASH avoid the branching as it flushes the pipeline. This kind of delays are good only for the very short ones. Anything longer should be implemented using the timers.

I advice to avoid delays in the code.

PS St-Link is not guilty :)

Comment: Dear Friend, I really read the documentation, and could not find explanation to this kind of stall, the prefech buffer should solve the issue regardless of the wait states, but looks like not. That was my understanding. I really agree with you, I use one timer to make milliseconds delay, but the functions are heritage from some old functions and microseconds are needed. Thanks a lot. By de way, some assembly is always enjoyable.

Comment: @CharlesBorgesdeLima - when you branch the pipeline is flushed. Same if any exception (including interrupt) handling routine is invoked.

Comment: I have tested with several increment instructions just to see the results without branch instruction, and the results was 2 cycles per instructions, so I still could not solve the puzzle. The same code above work perfect on ATSAM at 84MHz, of course the memory implementation is different, but the prefetch buffer on STM32 should work.

Comment: I will repeat the test again to see if I did not make some confusion during my several tests. Why the code work perfect at 24MHz?

Comment: Because there are no waitstates. If you have read the Reference Manual (and you claimed that you have which is obviously not the the truth) on the page 57 you have the explanation.

Comment: zero wait state, if 0 < SYSCLK ≤ 24 MHz
one wait state, if 24 MHz < SYSCLK ≤ 48 MHz two wait states, if 48 MHz < SYSCLK ≤ 72 MHz.

Comment: This I read several times, maybe I did not understand. If there is a prefetch buffer that read 2x64 bits (4 instructions), it should virtually compensate the wait states, (without branches, etc...). If  not , I did really not understand that pice of hardware use.

Comment: when you conditionally branch (or interrupt is invoked) the pipeline is flushed . After the flush it has to read from the FLASH  and has to wait.

Comment: Thanks, I will try my code with just increment instructions to see the results, I had tried it before without branch and got 2 cycles (because this kind of stall I knew should occur). I will redo the test to confirm if I did not make any mistake on cycle count, I was not using interrupt.

Comment: On more question: the STM32F103 should have some branch prediction? Shouldn't? On ATSAM, my piece of code worked perfect. Of course I Know that there are hardware differences.

Comment: M3 is a very old one. No branch predictor. Actually it is a bit more complicated. Pipelie decodes two instructons - if condition is met and if not. But because of the number of stages the next ones are not fetched until the actual branch. So after the conditional branch the next ones have to be read. It works like a flush without the flush.

Comment: Thanks I lot for your time, I really appreciate. And thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing several tests. My first conclusion is that the overhead depends on the alignment of the instructions on memory (the prefetch buffer is 2x64bits).
Second, because of the deterministic behavior of the branch, when taken, it flushes the prefetch buffer and also the pipeline.

Comment: Instead of making the false assumptions - just read the documentation. If you want to learn more about prefetching  and pipelining  read the arm website. Everything is explained there.

Comment: BTW address of the instruction shows if it is a thumb or arm instruction. Instructions are always word aligned. Odd addresses - thumb.

Comment: Unfortunately some Stack Overflow users are not so polite.

Comment: You put your comment as the answer - the answer is wrong. I wrote you already - instead doing the wrong assumptions - read the documentation. The address is odd to indicate the instruction set.

Comment: ATSAM3AX8 has Enhanced Flash controller, why my code work perfect. It is also a cortex-M3. So, you should understand better the question before make your explanations. It is easy to say to read the documentation without try to clearly answer the question.